# Laravel4: Change order of parameters when using Route::controller

Tags: routes, laravel-4

If I have the following defined:

*in app/routes.php*

```
Route::controller('prefix', 'MyClass@getMethod')
```

*in app/controllers/MyClass.php*

```
class MyClass {
  public function getMethod($param) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The route that will be available is `/prefix/method/{param}`.

Is it possible change this to `/prefix/{param}/method` without explicitly defining the route and thus just keeping `Route::controller`?

Note: the change of order can be applied to all methods of the class.

Thanks

Comment: No... not the I'm aware of. That's why we declare routes, so they be followed. Declare one thing and use another, simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to change order. Just edit the URI parameter at below

Your Routing :

```
Route::controller('prefix/{param}', 'MyController'); // Effects to All Controller Methods
```

OR

```
Route::controller('prefix/{param}', 'MyController@getMethod'); // Effects to specified Method
```

Keep the same controller. You don't need to change anyting.

The Result is `/prefix/{param}/method`

Comment: Oh god, of course... Should have known that... :) Thanks.